# How to apply logical opertaor condition on filters using pivottable.js

Tags: pivottable.js

I am using pivottable.js to create dynamic report but the problem is i could not figure out where to apply logical operators on selected column filter

example data :

```
var mdata = [
{
    "id": "1",      
    "billedamount": 120.00,
    "totalappliedamount": 220.00,
    "balance": -100.00,
    "primarypayment": 104.90,
    "patientpayment": 20.00
},
{
    "id": "2",  
    "patient": "Nicole Ruisi-1000163",
    "billedamount": 920.00,
    "totalappliedamount": 1261.00,
    "balance": -341.00,
    "primarypayment": 757.78,
    "patientpayment": 0.00
},
{
    "id": "3",  
    "patient": "MELISSA LANDON-1000487",
    "billedamount": 250.00,
    "totalappliedamount": 280.00,
    "balance": -30.00,
    "primarypayment": 124.26,
    "patientpayment": 30.00
}]
```

Now what i want is select all data where (billedamount > 50 OR balance > 0 ) AND totalappliedamount > 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `filter` parameter to pre-filter data: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Parameters